# Git repo file that needs to run in nodeJS

Tags: node.js, github

i'm not familiar with git and nodejs. I'm just interested with this repo and I want it to test and see for my self. There's a instruction in readme but I'm not familiar with nodejs. I try it but i'm stuck, i've done something wrong.

[Repo Link that I want to run and see in nodejs](https://github.com/themaxsandelin/amazingchat)

I'm stuck here[image]

Comment: Next step: open http://localhost:8000

Comment: i thought it is localhost:3000 / localhost:8080 :/ that's why. It works now thanks :)